# SQL cant see full name in data text field in ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net

I can see Surname and Lastname in asp when I select it for the data text field. But I can't select the full name

This is the SQL code I use to make the full name

```
select Voornaam + ' ' + Tussenvoegsel + ' ' + Achternaam as FullName from users
```

And in aspx

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Voornaam" DataValueField="Tussenvoegsel"></asp:ListBox>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:introaspdotnetConnectionString1 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [users] WHERE [Username] = @Username" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [users] ([Voornaam], [Tussenvoegsel], [Achternaam], [Username], [Wachtwoord]) VALUES (@Voornaam, @Tussenvoegsel, @Achternaam, @Username, @Wachtwoord)" SelectCommand="SELECT [Voornaam], [Tussenvoegsel], [Achternaam], [Username], [Wachtwoord] FROM [users]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [users] SET [Voornaam] = @Voornaam, [Tussenvoegsel] = @Tussenvoegsel, [Achternaam] = @Achternaam, [Wachtwoord] = @Wachtwoord WHERE [Username] = @Username">
```

Comment: That is because you have aliased it to FullName in SQL but are referencing it still as Voornaam & Tussenvoegsel in the DataTextField and DataValueField respectively.  Update those to FullName

Comment: @Dijkgraaf In SQL selecteer ik alleen die 3 en noem het dan FullName maar hij vind het dan niet in ASP

Comment: On the main Stackoverflow site you are expected to use English.  In your Select Command in the aspx you are selecting the three individual fields.  Update that with your SQL to make the full name.